# cannot install .net framework 4

Tags: .net-framework

I am having trouble installing .Net 4 on my computer, below is the install log. What could be causing this?

```
OS Version = 6.1.7600, SP = 0.0, Platform 2
OS Description = Windows 7 - x86 Ultimate Edition 
MSI = 5.0.7600.16992
Windows version =  x86_windowsfoundation_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_03103096f1ed527c.manifest
Windows servicing = 6.1.7601.17592
CommandLine = D:\6e5d7fa491f94510a965bc9351aa8b\\Setup.exe /x86 /x64
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Beta Setup
Package Version = 4.5.50131
User Experience Data Collection Policy: AlwaysUploaded
Number of applicable items: 8
Exe (D:\6e5d7fa491f94510a965bc9351aa8b\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
ServiceControl operation succeeded!
Exe (D:\6e5d7fa491f94510a965bc9351aa8b\Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x86.msu) failed with 0x8e5e03fb - (null).
Exe Log File: CBS.log
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x8E5E03FB) (Elapsed time: 0 00:01:50)
```

Comment: Can you make a effort to clean this up and ask a question? Just pasting a bunch of text in does not make is a good question. It may be helpful to take a minute to read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Your question would be more likely to get answers if you provide more detail, such as what version of Windows you're running, what steps you've tried so far to solve the problem yourself, and anything that has changed on your computer recently.  Welcome and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to install the BETA for the 4.5 framework.  Get the actual released version.

Regardless, 4.5 [requires SP1 for windows to be installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx).  From your OS version, it's apparent you don't have SP1 (or probably any updates) installed.

To resolve this:

1. [Install Service Pack 1 for Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/service-packs-download#sptabs=win7).  I'd go further to recommend that you install every single update that has been released.  Click the start button and type "windows update" and read the directions.
2. [Install the release version of the 4.5 framework.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)
3. Go through Windows update to get any remaining patches.